# Wagtail template not loading

Tags: django, wagtail

I'm trying to set up a small Wagtail blog, it's inside of an existing Django project. 
I've tried following the official wagtail documentation but I'm failing to view my template, instead I'm greeted with "Welcome to your new Wagtail site!" 
The tree for my blog app looks like this

```
    blog
├── admin.py
├── apps.py
├── __init__.py
├── migrations
│   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   ├── 0002_auto_20171121_0949.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __pycache__
│       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-36.pyc
│       ├── 0002_auto_20171121_0949.cpython-36.pyc
│       └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
├── models.py
├── __pycache__
│   ├── admin.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── models.cpython-36.pyc
│   └── urls.cpython-36.pyc
├── templates
│   └── blog
│       └── blog_page.html
├── tests.py
├── urls.py
└── views.py
```

All the other files I refrence here are from this tree. 
The models.py looks like this

```
from wagtail.wagtailcore.models import Page
from wagtail.wagtailcore.fields import RichTextField
from wagtail.wagtailadmin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel


class BlogPage(Page):
    intro = RichTextField(blank=True)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('body', classname="full"),
    ]
```

urls.py from model app

```
from wagtail.wagtailadmin import urls as wagtailadmin_urls
from wagtail.wagtaildocs import urls as wagtaildocs_urls
from wagtail.wagtailcore import urls as wagtail_urls
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^cms/', include(wagtailadmin_urls)),
    url(r'^documents/', include(wagtaildocs_urls)),
    #from /blog is where our blog will reside
    url(r'^', include(wagtail_urls)),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

blog_page.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load wagtailcore_tags %}

{% block body_class %}template-blogindexpage{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>

    <div class="Why is this not working?">{{ page.intro|richtext }}</div>

    {% for post in page.get_children %}
        <h2><a href="{% pageurl post %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
        {{ post.specific.intro }}
        {{ post.specific.body|richtext }}
    {% endfor %}
    <h1>Hello world!</h1>

{% endblock %}
```

and finally the urls.py in my project root

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('homepage.urls')),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

]
```

Sorry for posting all this code, but I don't know where the error could be. Thank you for all replies! From what I gather from the documentation Wagtail should fond blog_page.html because class BlogPage looks for a "blog_page" view name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By creating the `BlogPage` class and template, you've defined `BlogPage` as a new page *type*, but you haven't created an actual page of that type yet. You now need to go into the Wagtail admin at `/cms`, and create and publish a new page alongside the existing "Welcome to your new Wagtail site!" page. You then need to go to Settings -> Sites and update the record to point to that new page.

Comment: I was not aware of that, but when creating a new page (or editing the existing) in Wagtail admin I can't find my blog_page.html at all. I've run migrations.

I was looking for it in "Root page" (settings)editing the default, trying to make a new page and while editing the "Pages"

Comment: I had to create a child page to see my view, seems a bit weird and it stops me from having all blog posts at /blog it seems. but it works. Thank you for the help!